# Add Hierarchical Index column with respect to a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

This is the input table

[image]

Output Table should be

[image]

Input table in text format

Code Index

```
A
A01
A01.111 
A01.236 
A01.236.249 
A01.236.500 
A01.378 
A01.378.100 
A01.378.610
A01.378.610.050 
A01.378.610.100
B
B01
B01.043
B01.043.075 
B01.043.075.189 
B01.043.075.189.250 
B01.043.075.189.250.150 
B01.043.075.189.250.150.160 
B01.043.075.189.250.150.160.170 
B01.043.075.189.250.250 
B01.044
B01.043.076
B01.043.075.190
B01.043.075.189.251
B01.043.075.189.250.151
B01.043.075.189.250.150.161
B01.043.075.189.250.150.160.171
B01.043.075.189.250.251 
B01.045
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I couldn't get any idea, what should I do

Comment: If possible then could you please add raw data instead of image?

Comment: I have added the data in text format

Comment: Does current answer match your requirements?

Comment: yes, but the below solution is not working

Comment: @YashPatil Below solution is not working? Can you give some details? Are you facing any errors or the output is not what you expected?

Comment: Table the text input and I want the output from the image but below code is giving wrong output for B

Comment: @YashPatil Well, if you do not want to add a single point after the upper letters, I've updated my answer and it works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question. I've tried to play with the `Series.str` class of `pandas` but I have no idea how to deal with this in a vector-computational way since the number of hierarchy levels may be very large.

Here I give a simple for-loop method. It might be very slow if your data is very large, but it does work at least.

With this encapsulated function:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

def get_index(data):
    hierarchy = OrderedDict()
    data = re.sub(r"([A-Z])(\d)", r"\1.\2", data)
    results = []
    for line in data.splitlines():
        if line:
            this_hier = hierarchy
            indices = []
            for hier in line.split("."):
                if hier:
                    if not hier in this_hier:
                        this_hier.update({hier: OrderedDict()})
                    # Remove `+1` if you'd like indices start from 0
                    indices.append(list(this_hier.keys()).index(hier) + 1)
                    this_hier = this_hier[hier]
            results.append(".".join(map(str, indices)))
        else:
            results.append("")
    return results
```

And with your data:

```
data = """A
A01
A01.111 
A01.236 
A01.236.249 
A01.236.500 
A01.378 
A01.378.100 
A01.378.610
A01.378.610.050 
A01.378.610.100
B
B01
B01.043
B01.043.075 
B01.043.075.189 
B01.043.075.189.250 
B01.043.075.189.250.150 
B01.043.075.189.250.150.160 
B01.043.075.189.250.150.160.170 
B01.043.075.189.250.250 
B01.044
B01.043.076
B01.043.075.190
B01.043.075.189.251
B01.043.075.189.250.151
B01.043.075.189.250.150.161
B01.043.075.189.250.150.160.171
B01.043.075.189.250.251 
B01.045
"""
```

You can get and output the results with:

```
indices = get_index(data)
for text, idx in zip(data.splitlines(), indices):
    print(f"{text:<40}{idx}")
```

And the output will be:

```
A                                       1
A01                                     1.1
A01.111                                 1.1.1
A01.236                                 1.1.2
A01.236.249                             1.1.3.1
A01.236.500                             1.1.3.2
A01.378                                 1.1.4
A01.378.100                             1.1.5.1
A01.378.610                             1.1.5.2
A01.378.610.050                         1.1.5.2.1
A01.378.610.100                         1.1.5.2.2
B                                       2
B01                                     2.1
B01.043                                 2.1.1
B01.043.075                             2.1.1.1
B01.043.075.189                         2.1.1.2.1
B01.043.075.189.250                     2.1.1.2.2.1
B01.043.075.189.250.150                 2.1.1.2.2.2.1
B01.043.075.189.250.150.160             2.1.1.2.2.2.2.1
B01.043.075.189.250.150.160.170         2.1.1.2.2.2.2.2.1
B01.043.075.189.250.250                 2.1.1.2.2.2.3
B01.044                                 2.1.2
B01.043.076                             2.1.1.3
B01.043.075.190                         2.1.1.2.3
B01.043.075.189.251                     2.1.1.2.2.3
B01.043.075.189.250.151                 2.1.1.2.2.2.4
B01.043.075.189.250.150.161             2.1.1.2.2.2.2.3
B01.043.075.189.250.150.160.171         2.1.1.2.2.2.2.2.2
B01.043.075.189.250.251                 2.1.1.2.2.2.5
B01.045                                 2.1.3
```

Some illustration:

1. `OrderedDict` of `collections` is used to guarantee that Python<3.7 can also run this.
2. The hierarchical levels of the OP's data are kind of unnatural since all levels are separated with a single dot `.` except the first level where there're no separators such as `A01`. So I suggest adding a dot between them(e.g. `A.01`), or, automatically add one. That's why there's a `data = re.sub(r"([A-Z])(\d)", r"\1.\2", data)` line in my code. This could keep your code pretty.